# Break on ForEach() dart

Tags: flutter, dart, foreach

I'm writing a function where I iterate thru a map and look test for valid values on an function. My question is there is a better way to correctly break from a foreach loop when an error is found? 
(***'break'*** does not work on foreach())

Since I am not able to use the break function here so i had to place a bool marker :/

Any help in making this code nice looking would be appreciated :)

```
  Future<bool> saveToKeychainFunc(Map data) {
    bool saved = false;
    bool error = false;

    data?.keys?.forEach((item) async {
      if (data[item] != null) {
        await _storage.write(key: item.toString(), value: data[item].toString());
      } else {
        //TODO
        // data error, we got null for a value!
        error = true;
      }
      saved = true;
    });

    return (error == true) ? false : saved;
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've experienced this. My work around is using `for` loop instead.

ex:

```
for (int i = 0; i < jsonTransactions.length; i++) {
    Transaction transaction = Transaction.fromJson(jsonTransactions[i]);
    transactions.add(transaction);
}
```

You can just add conditions, and add your `break` inside the loop if conditions are met. Since you're using a map, my code should not be very different since `Map` also has `.length`

Comment: It's also pointless to have another async function inside since your Future<bool> function is already async.